# Deploy InnoDB Cluster on Kubernetes without SSL

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, cluster-computing, innodb

I Searched the Internet for hours but without any luck finding a tutorial for my Problem. I have a selfhosted K8s-Cluster on which I try to deploy an InnoDB-Cluster. I want to use it as a Kubernetes-wide MySQL-Cluster for a couple of Deployments. Not all of them allow SSL-Connections.

I installed the MySQL-Operator without any problems using helm.

When it comes to de Cluster and Router itself I am stuck. How do I setup the cluster, that connections are allowed without using TLS/SSL? I cannot find a description of the option when I try to install the Cluster also using Helm:

```
helm install mycluster mysql-operator/mysql-innodbcluster \
--set credentials.root.user='root' \
--set credentials.root.password='sakila' \
--set credentials.root.host='%' \
--set serverInstances=3 \
--set routerInstances=1 \
--set tls.useSelfSigned=false
```

I am glad if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to use the `mysql-operator/mysql-innodbcluster` operator, then it always uses TLS, the only thing you can change is to use self-signed TLS by setting up the following parameter.

```
tls.useSelfSigned=true
```

You can check all the operator parameters [here](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/mysql-operator/mysql-innodbcluster?modal=values).

Comment: Thank you, so I think I change to percona.